# asp.net c# to json how to store data without overwriting existing data

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, webforms

So I am having a lot of trouble converting data between a JSON file and C#. So far I can easily add data to the JSON file through a Asp.net form which is great, but it overwrites any existing data that is there and basically I want to add to the file without this happening.

Below is the C# code for what I want to achieve. I believe I am so close and as you can see I try put the JSON file into a string before adding and then adding them both back to the file after the new data is added through separate strings, but it just doesn't work.

Heads up: I am new to this and I have researched on this site and Google for hours if not days trying to understand where I'm going wrong since I know it's super easy but I just don't get it.

```
public partial class AddBook : System.Web.UI.Page
{
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    const string FILENAME = "Books.json";
    string fullFileName = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, FILENAME);

    string jsonText2 = File.ReadAllText(fullFileName);
    BookCollection bookCollection2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<BookCollection>(jsonText2);

    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {

        if (Session["EditDetails"] != null && (Boolean)Session["editDetails"] == true)
        {
            BookYear(DDLYear);
        }
        else
        {
            BookYear(DDLYear);
        }
    }
    else if(IsPostBack) {


            String BookID = TxtBookID.Text;
            String Title = TxtTitle.Text;
            String Author = TxtAuthor.Text;
            String Year = DDLYear.Text;
            String Publisher = TxtPublisher.Text;
            String ISBN = TxtISBN.Text;

            BookCollection bookCollection = new BookCollection();

            Book book = new Book(BookID, Title, Author, Year, Publisher, ISBN);
            bookCollection.books.Add(book);


            string jsonText = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(bookCollection);
            File.WriteAllText(fullFileName, jsonText);
            jsonText2 = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(bookCollection);


    }
}
protected void BookYear(DropDownList dropDownList)
{
    int yr = DateTime.Now.Year;
    dropDownList.Items.Insert(0, "Select Year");
    for (int x = 1900; x < yr; x++)
    {
        dropDownList.Items.Add(x.ToString());
    }
}

protected void BtnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl);
    //String BookID = TxtBookID.Text;
    //String Title = TxtTitle.Text;
    //String Author = TxtAuthor.Text;
    //String Year = DDLYear.Text;
    //String Publisher = TxtPublisher.Text;
    //String ISBN = TxtISBN.Text;

    //const string FILENAME = "Books.json";
    //string fullFileName = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, FILENAME);

    //BookCollection bookCollection = new BookCollection();

    //Book book = new Book(BookID, Title, Author, Year, Publisher, ISBN);
    //bookCollection.books.Add(book);

    //string jsonText = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(bookCollection);
    //File.WriteAllText(fullFileName, jsonText);

}

}
```

I also have separate classes

```
public class Book
{

public String id { get; set; }
public string title { get; set; }
public string author { get; set; }
public String year { get; set; }
public string publisher { get; set; }
public String isbn { get; set; }

public Book(String id, string title, string author, String year, string 
publisher, String isbn)
{
    this.id = id;
    this.title = title;
    this.author = author;
    this.year = year;
    this.publisher = publisher;
    this.isbn = isbn;
}
```

and

```
public class BookCollection
 {

public List<Book> books { get; set; }

public BookCollection()
{
    this.books = new List<Book>();
}


}
```

Comment: Did you look at the documentation for [File.WriteAllText](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.writealltext(v=vs.110).aspx)? Maybe you should start there: `Creates a new file, write the contents to the file, and then closes the file. If the target file already exists, it is overwritten.`

Comment: The steps you *need* to take to append json to the file are: 1) Get the content you want to append. 2) read the existing content back into memory 3) Merge the data structures 4) Write the merged structure back to the file (now you *can* use the `File.WriteAllText`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure why you would want to keep the previous serialized data since it should be "old" when the new one is written. However, if you look at [the documentation for `File.WriteAllText`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143375(v=vs.110).aspx) (enphasis mine):

> Creates a new file, writes the specified string to the file, and then
>   closes the file. If the target file already exists, **it is overwritten**.

You have a couple of options:

1. Read the current text and write it all using `File.WriteAllText`
2. Use other `File` methods, like [`File.AppendText`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.appendtext(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Creates a StreamWriter that appends UTF-8 encoded text to an existing
>   file, or to a new file if the specified file does not exist.

However, if you'd like to keep all the `BookCollection` as a list on the file, I'd suggest you to write/read the file as a `List<BookCollection>` so that you don't have to think about handling the different objects.

Comment: AppendText wouldn't yield a usable object the next time that it is deserialized

Comment: @KyleBurns I'm much aware of that, that's why the last part of my answer.

Comment: file.appendtext... how beautiful. now it adds to the file without erasing. thank you. i believe the last part of your answer refers to the fact that now in the JSON file it will create a new book everytime which is not allowed. i see the problem but i lack the skill to really fix it. i can see you have given the answer to that problem also but i dont really understand it. however i will play with the code until this List<bookCollection> works. thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "File.AppendAllText" method and here is the link:
this mehtod does not overwrite the JSON file.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.appendalltext?view=net-8.0

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).